# Prevent SQL injection on free response text fields in classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-injection

I've got some free-response text fields and I'm not sure how to scrub them to prevent SQL injection. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd have found the answer yourself if you'd searched http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlinjection.

Comment: @John you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection+asp-classic and yet one of those were marked as duplicated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a [parameterized query](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of concatenating the user's input into the query.

Here is how to do this in classic asp:
http://blog.binarybooyah.com/blog/post/Classic-ASP-data-access-using-parameterized-SQL.aspx

It's also important to note that the only way you can be 100% safe from sql injection is to parameterize any sql statement that uses user input, even once it's in the database. Example: Say you take user input via a parameterized query or stored procedure. You will be safe on the insert, however you need to make sure that anything down the road that uses that input also uses a parameter. Directly concatenating user input is a bad idea anywhere, including inside the db.

Comment: And if you have to write classic ASP, do it in JScript, much nicer! And, IIRC, performs better too.

Comment: @OrbMan:  How is that at all relevant??  JScript is nicer if you don't mind isolating yourself however the vast majority of ASP is in VBScript.  Frankly if you have to use classic ASP do it in VBScript, its a lot easier to integrate examples and will be easier for other typical ASP devs to read.

Answer (score 0):

Call a [stored](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=32141) [procedure](http://www.coderanch.com/t/303581/JDBC/java/Stored-Procedure-VS-normal-Query).

**EDIT**: Just to clarify. Building dynamic sql in a sp can of course be just as dangerous as doing it in the app, but binding user inputs into a query will protect you against sql injection, as described here (oracle-specific discussion, but the principle applies elsewhere):

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:23863706595353

> It is not dynamic sql that is the
>   issue (all sql is dynamic in Oracle
>   actually -- even  static sql in
>   pro*c/plsql!).  It is "the
>   construction" of this sql that is the
>   problem. If a user gives you inputs -
>   they should be BOUND into the query --
>   not concatenated.   The second you
>   concatenate user input into your SQL
>   -- it is as if you gave them the  ability to pass you code and you
>   execute that code.  Plain and simple.

Comment: Don't believe it.  It's a myth that stored procedures protect against SQL injection vulnerabilities.  You're just as likely to build an unsafe dynamic SQL query in a procedure as in application code.

Comment: I'm not advocating building dynamic sql within a sp, but providing the text field entries as parameters to a parameterised statement within the sp.